# Does AMP/ATP ratio affect lifespan in vertebrates?

Tags: senescence

The [reference below](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC535911/) says that a higher AMP/ATP ratio is associated with lower lifespan in *C. elegans*.

Is this finding also generalizable to vertebrates as well?

---

Reference:
Apfeld, J., O’Connor, G., McDonagh, T., DiStefano, P. S. & Curtis, R. The AMP-activated 
protein kinase AAK-2 links energy levels and insulin-like signals to lifespan in C. elegans. 
Genes Dev. 18, 3004–3009 (2004). [PMCID: PMC535911](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC535911/).

Comment: Interesting, but I am not sure how useful studies into many of these processes  which *shorten* lifespan actually are. There are many drugs/poisons which have deleterious effects on organisms, but they don't tell us much about  longevity or the aging process. Better to focus on drugs/interventions which extend lifespan?

Answer (score 6):

There are many papers suggesting a link between AMPK (the major cellular sensor of the AMP/ATP ratio) and lifespan.  As with most of these sorts of experiments, I think it is currently unclear precisely what the mechanism for this is, but AMPK regulates TORC1 and autophagy, both of which are also important for lifespan regulation.  Here is a PubMed link to [search results](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=ampk%20aging).